# Getting a value from a Do-While function

Tags: c#, do-while

```
decimal price = 0;
        do
        {
            ++count;
            Console.Write("Item {0}", count);
            Console.Write("     Enter Price: $ ");
            price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
       
        } while ( price != -1);
```

I need to be able to store every iteration of "price" that is made. But I haven't been able to do it without my values being overwritten. I'm new to C# and not really sure what to do.

Comment: This is the reason arrays are invented. Better yet, resizable arrays, or as they called in C# collections. The most general use one is `List<T>`.

Comment: You need a place to "store" the values. There are a plethora of options, ranging from in-memory storage like arrays and lists, to file storage, to database access, or even cloud storage. Please [edit] the question with more details to make it easier for people to answer effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
List<decimal> prices  = new List<decimal>();

decimal price=0;
int count=0;

        do
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Item {0}", count);
            Console.WriteLine("     Enter Price: $ ");
            price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            prices.Add(price);
       
        } while ( price != -1);

Console.WriteLine ("Price history:");

foreach(var item in prices)
{
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store your prices in a dictionary as to ensure that prices for the same item have not been added. Here is a fiddle with an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uZQqDp

```
public static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, decimal> prices = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();

    int count = 0;
    bool finished = false;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Item {0}:\tEnter Price: $", count);

        var price = Console.ReadLine();
        var convertedPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(price);
        
        if(convertedPrice != -1)
        {
            prices.Add(count, convertedPrice);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    } while(!finished);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Price History");
    foreach(var price in prices)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item {0}:\tPrice: ${1}", price.Key, price.Value);
    }
}
```